# Pandas GroupBy - How to Keep Rows Up to Percentage of Cumulative Sum?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, percentage

I have a dataframe which is not ordered:

```
df
     A   B  Moves
0   E1  E2     10
1   E1  E3     20
2   E1  E4     15
3   E2  E1      9
4   E2  E3      8
5   E2  E4      7
6   E3  E1     30
7   E3  E2     32
8   E3  E4     40
9   E4  E1      5
10  E4  E2     20
11  E4  E3      3
```

I want to return rows `B` until their cumulative sum adds up to some minimum % of the overall total `Moves` for each grouping of `B` in `A` (where I take the highest first).

Once the % threshold is reached, I stop taking rows (a cumulative sum). The procedure must be "greedy" in that if a row takes it above the desired % it includes that row.

If the minimum percentage of the total is 50%, then I want to return first:

**Desired Output**

```
     A   B  Moves
    E1  E3     20
    E1  E4     15
    E2  E1      9
    E2  E3      8
    E3  E4     40
    E3  E2     32
    E4  E2     20
```

I would then want to extract the row names for each grouping using `df.groupby(...).apply(list)` from[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

```
A     Most_Moved
E1      [E3, E4] 
E2      [E1, E3]
E3      [E4, E2]
E4          [E2]
```

**What I've tried:**

I can return the Total_Moves ordered using `cumsum` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872565/reversed-cumulative-sum-of-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) question:

```
df.groupby(by=['A','B']).sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()[::-1]

       Moves
A  B        
E4 E3     28
   E2     25
   E1      5
E3 E4    102
   E2     62
   E1     30
E2 E4     24
   E3     17
   E1      9
E1 E4     45
   E3     30
   E2     10
```

Separately I can return the total moves (sum) for each group:

```
df.groupby(by="A").sum()

    Moves
A        
E1     45
E2     24
E3    102
E4     28
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby) question  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683498/pandas-groupby-percentage-above-threshold) question I can return each row as a percentage of the sum for that category:

```
df.groupby(by=["A"])["Moves"].apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))

0     22.222222
1     44.444444
2     33.333333
3     37.500000
4     33.333333
5     29.166667
6     29.411765
7     31.372549
8     39.215686
9     17.857143
10    71.428571
11    10.714286
```

**What doesn't work**

However, if I combine these, it evaluates the percentage of the overall rows:

```
df.groupby(by=["A", "B"])["Moves"].agg({"Total_Moves":sum}).sort_values("Total_Moves", ascending=False).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))

       Total_Moves
A  B              
E3 E4    20.100503
   E2    16.080402
   E1    15.075377
E1 E3    10.050251
E4 E2    10.050251
E1 E4     7.537688
   E2     5.025126
E2 E1     4.522613
   E3     4.020101
   E4     3.517588
E4 E1     2.512563
   E3     1.507538
```

This evaluates the percentage across the entire dataframe, not within the individual groups.

I just can't figure out how to piece this together to get my output.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `groupby.apply` with a custom function

```
def select(group, pct=50):
    # print(group)
    moves = group['Moves'].sort_values(ascending=False)
    cumsum = moves.cumsum() / moves.sum()
    # print(cumsum)
    # `cumsum` is the cumulative contribution of the sorted moves
    idx = len(cumsum[cumsum < pct/100]) + 1
    # print(idx)
    # `idx` is the first index of the move which has a cumulative sum of `pct` or higher
    idx = moves.index[:idx]  
    # print(idx)
    # here, `idx` is the Index of all the moves in with a cumulative contribution of `pct` or higher
    # print(group.loc[idx])
    return group.loc[idx].set_index(['B'], drop=True)['Moves']
    # return a Series of Moves with column `B` as index of the items which have index `idx`
```

> ```
> df.groupby('A').apply(select)
> ```

```
        Moves
A   B   
E1  E3  20
    E4  15
E2  E1  9
    E3  8
E3  E4  40
    E2  32
E4  E2  20
```

## edit

I've added some comments to the code. To make even more clear what it does, I also added (commented) print statements of the intermediary variables. If you uncomment them, don't be surprised that the first group gets printed [twice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply)

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Perfect - this works on my example above and on my real dataset.

Comment: Thanks for adding comments.

Comment: Thank you so much Maarten, this is really an underrated answer!